# Merge two DF based on the first match

Tags: python, pandas

Having the following DFs:

```
Data frame A
    A   B
0   a   x
1   b   y
2   c   z

Data frame B
    X   Y   V
0   a   x   v1
1   b   y   v2
2   c   o   v3
3   a   x   v4
```

I've tried to merge on `[A,B]` & `[X,Y]` in order to get the following result, where the first match is saved and the other are being ignored, and `NaN` values for no match.

```
    A   B   X   Y   V
0   a   x   a   x   v1  <-- first match of 'a','x'
1   b   y   b   y   v2
2   c   z   NaN NaN NaN <-- no match for c,z
```

From the above example, the ignored row from DF B is:

```
3   a   x   v4
```

However my code,

```
a = pd.DataFrame({"A":['a','b','c'], "B":['x','y','z']})
b = pd.DataFrame({"X":['a','b','c','a'], "Y":['x','y','o','x'], "V":['v1','v2','v3','v4']})
pd.merge(a,b,left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['X','Y'])
```

Outputs the following:

```
A   B   X   Y   V
0   a   x   a   x   v1
1   a   x   a   x   v4
2   b   y   b   y   v2
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: I think you can try `a.merge(b.drop_duplicates(['X', 'Y']), left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['X','Y'], how='left')
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the merge 'how' to 'left' (default is inner), then drop duplicates on A&B.

```py
result = pd.merge(a,b,left_on=['A','B'], right_on=['X','Y'], how='left')
result = result.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'])
```

Produces the following

```py
   A  B    X    Y    V
0  a  x    a    x   v1
2  b  y    b    y   v2
3  c  z  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Excellent, what I was looking for